# Exporting mysql html table to excel file

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am trying to query a mysql database and display data in a table.I now want to take the table and make a button that allows you to export it to an excel file.now you were able to export to excel,but its showing an `error Notice: Undefined variable: data`

Below is my code:

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "export";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Could not select database");

$values =mysql_query( "SELECT name,email,phone,nationality,dob FROM users order by id");

$header = "Name" . "\t";
$header .= "Email" . "\t";
$header .= "Phone" . "\t";
$header .= "Nationality" . "\t";
$header .= "DOB" . "\t";

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($values)){
$row1 = array();


$row1[] = $row['name'];
$row1[] = $row['email'];
$row1[] = $row['phone'];
$row1[] = $row['nationality'];
$row1[] = $row['dob'];

$data .= join("\t", $row1)."\n";
   }
header("Content-type: application/x-msdownload");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=expot.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print "$header\n$data"; 
exit(); 
?>
```

Comment: Move your initialisation of `$row1 = array();` outside of the `foreach` loop

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks but all the value showing in same line ,not showing one by one

Comment: Then move your headers above the `while` loop, and try using PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function to create your file to php://output rather than building up all this data in memory

Comment: can you please modify my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code contains the statement:

```
$data .= join("\t", $row1)."\n";
```

This is where you're concatenating a string to an existing variable `$data`. However, no such variable exists. You should add somewhere near the top of your code:

```
$data = "";
```

to initialize the `$data` variable.

Comment: thanks ,now error is not displaying,but it only taking the last value in the html table ,not taking the all data

Comment: Are you sure you put the `$data = ""` outside the while loop?

Answer (score 3):

Because you never initialize the `$data` variable.

Put:

```
$data = '';
```

at the beginning of your code, before the while cycle.

Comment: thanks ,now error is not displaying,but it only taking the last value in the html table ,not taking the all data